# Offset scroll to anchor tags when clicked from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to refine the offset for anchor tags clicked from another page. I tried mixing my smooth scroll script with a solution from another post in StackOverflow and came up with this:

```
if ( window.location.hash ) scroll(0,0);
// void some browsers issue
setTimeout( function() { scroll(0,0); }, 1);
if ( window.location.hash ) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top +75
    }, 5);
}
// in-page anchors
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
    // if mobile menu is open, close it 
    if ($('#header-navigation.toggled').length) { 
        $('#header-navigation').removeClass('toggled');
    }
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top -150
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
// more scripts follow...
```

But the results aren't perfect, especially in IE. I also don't understand why the offset is a negative number for in-page anchors, but a positive one for referring anchors. I really like the way the smooth scroll works for in-page anchors, so I tried reworking as so:

```
//Set smooth scrolling for anchor tags
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
    // if mobile menu is open, close it 
    if ($('#header-navigation.toggled').length) { 
        $('#header-navigation').removeClass('toggled');
    }
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            if ($('#coi-hq-submenu').length) {
                // COI HQ needs higher offset for fixed submenu
                $('html,body').animate({
                   scrollTop: target.offset().top -150
                }, 500);
            } else {
                $('html,body').animate({
                   scrollTop: target.offset().top -50
                }, 500);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
});

// Offset anchors from referring pages
var referringTarget = window.location.hash;
if ( referringTarget ) {
    if ($('#coi-hq-submenu').length) {
        // COI HQ needs higher offset for fixed submenu
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(referringTarget).offset().top -150
        }, 5);
    } else {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(referringTarget).offset().top -50
        }, 5);
    }
    return false;
}
// more scripts follow...
```

This offsets referring urls perfectly, but return false; prevents the rest of my scripts from working. I tried (e)preventdefault; and (e)stopPropagation; - but no luck. If I remove return false; completely, I get a totally different offset.

How can I structure this to get the offset I want, but not prevent the rest of the scripts from working?